# Blank characters in Pygame .blit

Tags: python, pygame

In a program I'm creating it would be very useful if I could use the triple bar symbol (≡), however when trying to use surface.blit to get it to appear on screen, it instead shows up as a blank character.

So far no immediate solutions come to mind besides blitting 3 seperate bars, however that would be tedious for many reasons.